# Is there any way to restore a deleted report after emptying the recycle bin?

Tags: dashboard, joined-reports

I want to restore the deleted reports,the reports are deleted 60 days ago.I check it on RecycleBin but it have only the 15 days records so, Is there any other possibilities to restore it?

Thanks

VenkatSforce

Comment: Presumably you don't have a metadata backup of the report, like through Eclipse or MavensMate?

Comment: No @JeremyNottingham i don't have a backup..Is there any possibilities without backup?

Comment: Do you happen to have an old sandbox lying around that might have the report?

Answer (score 2):

Try to contact Saleforce Support. Just log a case. I think you chances are low, but worth a try. Let us know, if the were able to help you.

Comment: This. If the background physical delete process hasn't run yet *maybe* they can recover the record.

Answer (score 1):

Items are only available in the recycle bin for 15 days before they're automatically deleted by Salesforce. For more on this see [Using the Recycle Bin](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=home_delete.htm&language=en_US).

Comment: Thanks for the support @crmprogdev Once deleted from salesforce RecycleBin is there any possibilities to restore it? or need to contact the SFDC support..

Comment: You can try contacting support, but if its outside the 15 days, I wouldn't hold hold high hopes they'll be able to restore it for you. You definitely won't be able to restore it yourself beyond 15 days from deletion.